# Append table row to table using getElementByID?

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table, append, getelementbyid

I want to be able to append an additional row to my table. The way the code is now, it just adds two input boxes outside of the table regardless of where I insert it. When I inspect in my browser, it looks like the table tags have been stripped, is there something wrong with using the getElementByID function?.

My Hidden row to be added to the table:

```
<div id="rowToBeAdded" style="display: none">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /></td>
    <td><input style="margin-right:2em;" type="text" value="" name="newLinkTitle[]" size="50" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="http://" name="newLinkAddress[]" size="50" /></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

After the last `</tr>` of my table I have:

```
<span id="addRowHere">  
  <input type="button" id="moreFields" value="Add more links" onclick="init()" />
</span>
```

And here's my Javascript:

```
function init() {
  document.getElementById('moreFields').onclick = moreFields;
  moreFields();
}

function moreFields() {
  var newFields = document.getElementById('rowToBeAdded').cloneNode(true);
  newFields.style.display = 'block';

  var newField = newFields.childNodes;
  var insertHere = document.getElementById('addRowHere');
  insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);

}
```

Comment: So your click calls init() which adds an onclick event?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, a TR can not be a child of a div element. And you can not append a div to a table.

Comment: How would I change it so that it would append the tr to the table?

Comment: Well make the div a table and clone the tr, not the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/yGVWM/3/   EDIT: fixed the remove button

```
document.getElementById('moreFields').onclick = addMoreFields;    //    set binding

var newRow = document.getElementById('rowTemplate').cloneNode(true),
    myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');

function addMoreFields() {
    myTable.appendChild(newRow.cloneNode(true));
}
```

And you should make a function for removing a line also. Try it yourself. And use classes and id to get your elements.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much :) I feel silly that it was so simple!

Comment: We all do in the beginning, that's the way you learn. Try to see some simple tutorials for jQuery and use it. It will help you